# Unable to pull a docker image inside minikube

Tags: docker, minikube

I am trying to pull an image in minikube vm.

```
minikube ssh
docker pull <docker registry>/<image name>/<tag>
```

It gives me error:

> Error response from daemon: Head "...url for image...": x509:
> certificate signed by unknown authority.

How can I solve it?

Comment: As we can see it could be the reason : The error message you received indicates that the Docker daemon encountered a problem with the SSL/TLS certificate of the image's URL. Specifically, it states that the certificate was signed by an unknown authority, which means the certificate authority (CA) that issued the certificate is not recognized or trusted by the Docker daemon.

Answer (score 1):

This `Error response from daemon: Head "...url for image...": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority` when the certificate you are using is not valid or when you are not using the correct certificate.

Below troubleshooting steps will help you to resolve your issue:

1.Check if you  already have it in your configuration, you can find it by going into the `/etc/docker/certs.d/`.
2.If you don’t find any certificate, restart the docker and [create a self-signed certificate](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/#use-self-signed-certificates) or [get a certificate](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#run-an-externally-accessible-registry).
3..If you find the certificate in the file try adding port as below, and make sure you have named the file extension with a crt extension

```
/etc/docker/certs.d/my-registry.example.com:5000/ca.crt
```

Then restart the docker, and check if the issue still persists.
4.If you are using `VPN or HTTP/HTTPS Proxy` try troubleshooting steps mentioned in this [official documentation](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/vpn_and_proxy/#x509-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authority).

For more information you can refer to the [document](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/protect-access/) as well as the [blog](https://velaninfo.com/rs/techtips/docker-certificate-authority/).